# Implement data generator in federated training

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

(I have posted the question on https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/issues/793 and maybe also here!)

I have customized my own data and model to federated interfaces and the training converged. But I am confused about an issue that in an images classification task, the whole dataset is extreme large and it can't be stored in a single `federated_train_data` nor be imported to memory for one time. So I need to load the dataset from the hard disk in batches to memory real-timely and use `Keras model.fit_generator` instead of `model.fit` during training, the approach people use to deal with large data.

I suppose in `iterative_process` shown in image classification tutorial, the model is fitted on a fixed set of data. Is there any way to adjust the code to let it fit to a data generator?I have looked into the source codes but still quite confused. Would be incredibly grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, TFF considers the feeding of data to be part of the "Python driver loop", which is a helpful distinction to make when writing TFF code.

In fact, when writing TFF, there are generally three levels at which one may be writing:

1. TensorFlow defining local processing (IE, processing that will happen on the clients, or on the server, or in the aggregators, or at any other placement one may want, but only a *single* placement.
2. Native TFF defining the way data is communicated *across* placements. For example, writing `tff.federated_sum` inside of a `tff.federated_computation` decorator; writing this line declares "this data is moved from clients to server, and aggregated via the sum operator".
3. Python "driving" the TFF loop, e.g. running a single round. It is the job of this final level to do what a "real" federated learning runtime would do; one example here would be selecting the clients for a given round.

If this breakdown is kept in mind, using a generator or some other lazy-evaluation-style construct to feed data in to a federated computation becomes relatively simple; it is just done at the Python level.

One way this could be done is via the [`create_tf_dataset_for_client`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/ClientData#create_tf_dataset_for_client) method on the `ClientData` object; as you loop over rounds, your Python code can select from the list of `client_ids`, then you can instantiate a new list of `tf.data.Datasets`and pass them in as your new set of client data. An example of this relatively simple usage would be [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/simple_fedavg/emnist_fedavg.py#L161), and a more advanced usage (involving defining a custom `client_datasets_fn` which takes `client_id` as a parameter, and passing it to a separately-defined training loop would be [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/gans/experiments/emnist/train.py#L354), in the code associated to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06679).

One final note: instantiating a `tf.data.Dataset` does not actually load the dataset into memory; the dataset is only loaded in when it is iterated over. One helpful tip I have received from the lead author of `tf.data.Dataset` is to think of `tf.data.Dataset` more as a "dataset recipe" than a literal instantiation of the dataset itself. It has been suggested that perhaps a better name would have been `DataSource` for this construct; hopefully that may help the mental model on what is actually happening. Similarly, using the `tff.simulation.ClientData` object generally shouldn't really load anything into memory until it is iterated over in training on the clients; this should make some nuances around managing dataset memory simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed instruction and I understand how to sample client ids now. The problem I am facing to use generator is that `Tensorflow.from_generator` reads data from disk batch by batch. I want to use it but I found that the client data in each round generated by `create_tf_dataset_for_client` is the whole dataset (or dataset recipe) for that round. If I want to use a batch data generator, I may need to change the model fit function to let it drive the batch iterator/generator, but I can't touch the client model fit function.

Comment: Hello @miaoz18
I am working on the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution (using the batch generator for TFL)?

Comment: Hi @miaoz18 . Did you find a solution to your question? I am having the same issue wherein I can't afford to keep all the training client data in a single array since the data is huge.